# Stationary points and gradient?

Tags: optimization

Wolfram Alpha tells me that $xy^2$ only has the stationary points (0,0).... but why?

We get the gradient $$(y^2 , 2xy)$$ and this is surely 0 as long as $y=0$ meaning $x$ can be whatever it wants to be and it'll still be a stationary point?

Comment: @Amzoti: Just as it says in the question, the solution is that $y$ must be zero, while $x$ can be arbitrary. Surely WA's answer is wrong (or incomplete, rather) here.

Comment: Yes, WolframAlpha is wrong. Someone tell [@in_wolframAlpha_we_trust](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/27030/in-wolframalpha-we-trust) the bad news...